# Do you need to update Ruby manually on a Mac?

Tags: ruby, macos

Ruby comes automatically installed on OS X. I assume when you get a new Mac it comes with the latest stable release of Ruby. Do you have to update it yourself manually over time, or does it get upgraded automatically when you upgrade your OS?

Comment: [Scripting language runtimes such as Python, Ruby, and Perl are included in macOS for compatibility with legacy software. Future versions of macOS won’t include scripting language runtimes by default, and might require you to install additional packages. If your software depends on scripting languages, it’s recommended that you bundle the runtime within the app.](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/macos_release_notes/macos_catalina_10_15_beta_9_release_notes). Use something else to manage Ruby versions (rbenv, rvm, asdf, etc).

Comment: OS X doesn't know which version(s) of Ruby you want to use (some Rubyists are still stuck on a decade-old version 1.8.x, usually not by choice), so no, the version is not automatically updated.  It's not version updating anyway, it's installing newer versions, which generally also requires that newer dependencies (e.g., gems) be installed as well, a task that is beyond every OS's  capabilities.

Comment: Install RVM with `\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable`; restart your shell; install Ruby with `rvm install 2.6`. [Don't](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/psa-do-not-use-system-ruby) [use](https://chrisherring.co/posts/why-you-shouldn-t-use-the-system-ruby) [system Ruby](http://billpatrianakos.me/blog/2014/05/15/never-use-system-ruby-ever/).

Comment: Further to @anothermh's comment, see the RVM docs at rvm.io.

Answer (score 3):

> I assume when you get a new Mac it comes with the latest stable release of Ruby.

No, it comes with whatever release Apple felt confident to support for the lifetime of the OS release.

> Do you have to update it yourself manually over time, or does it get upgraded automatically when you upgrade your OS?

Those two are not mutually exclusive.

Yes, it does get upgraded automatically, in order to, e.g., patch security vulnerabilities. However, an OS vendor will generally avoid updating anything they ship as part of the OS as much as possible, since they generally guarantee backwards-compatibility, and the easiest way to guarantee backwards-compatibility for third-party code that you have no control over, is to just not change it.

For example, macOS 10.14.6, which is the current release of macOS and was released 4 weeks ago, ships with Ruby 2.3.7, which was released 18 months ago.

The last release of Ruby 2.3 was Ruby 2.3.8, and the Ruby developers stopped providing security patches to Ruby 2.3 6 months ago. (Note that Apple *does* still provide security patches for Ruby 2.3 as part of macOS, though.)

So, yes, it does get upgraded automatically, with e.g. security fixes, but if you want a different version than the one shipped with the OS, you have to install it yourself.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: *No.*

Long answer:

If you just want a taste of Ruby, then no, you really don't need to do anything.

If you want to *use* Ruby to do something non-trivial, like beyond a "Hello, world!" application, then yes you should update.

The best approach is to use a Ruby version manager like [RVM](https://rvm.io) or [`rbenv`](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv) where you can get the latest version of Ruby, specific historical versions if necessary for testing, as well as alternate implementations like [JRuby](https://www.jruby.org) and [Rubinius](https://rubinius.com).

These version managers make it possible to have *multiple versions of Ruby installed simultaneously* and you can switch between at any time. You can even pin different projects at specific versions if they haven't been updated to work with the latest Ruby, a common problem with older code-bases.

This pattern plays out with any language, be it Ruby, Python, Perl, Node.js, C# or what have you. If you're doing serious development in those languages the first thing you do is install a version manager and the best version for your situation.